# Prestashop : changing the core controller behavior

Tags: prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I'm new with prestashop. and i would like to change a core controller behavior, Is it possible to change a controller behavior with a module in prestashop?
thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes via the overrides, look here: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors

Regards